# How to pass arguments to a function in setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
function fn($){
  return function(){
    innerFn = function(){
      setTimeout(show, 1000);
    };

    show = function(){
      $.alert("TEST");
    }
  }
}
```

But, after one second, when the function `show` is run, it says $ is undefined. How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: When and how is `fn` called? (And how is `show` called?)

Comment: on page loaded, call fn.like yui module.

Comment: `$` should be available in `show` if its defined when `fn` is called.

Comment: I tried closure, can't do it

Comment: but it can't.setTimeout context is window, it doesn't has $.

Comment: `$` is available to `show` because `show` is defined inside `fn`.  This isn't related to what context `setTimeout` has.

Comment: I also think it could be use, but it doesn't.

Comment: Could you give me your email or skype?

Comment: [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G8Qna/) shows that `$` is available inside `show`

Comment: @MarioDu doesn't take no for an answer. Use a goddam closure.

Answer (score 2):

> how to pass arguments to a function in setTimeout

setTimeout has a [built in mechanism](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout) for adding params

`var timeoutID = window.setTimeout(func, delay, [param1, param2, ...]);`

use it.

If you're going to use `this`  - you should be careful. but that's another question.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of things at play here. The most important being that your setTimeout never gets called, since innerFn never gets called. This should do the trick.

```
function fn($){
  return function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
      $.alert("TEST");
    }, 1000);
  }
}

fn(window)(); //triggers your alert after 1000ms
```

Comment: I called innerFn in other place, it's just a example.I want to know, like the code above, how to achieve?

Comment: In your current example your show function has access to the $ variable, since it is in a "parent" scope. There must be something else going on in your actual code.

Answer (score 1):

Your code makes no any sense, because nothing is called:

```
function fn($){
  return function(){
    innerFn = function(){
      setTimeout(show, 1000);
    };

    show = function(){
      $.alert("TEST");
    }
  }
}
```

Let's say I'm calling `fn` passing `window`, then a function is returned, that I can executed. But because this function is containing only function declaration - you also forget `var` so you pollute the global scope, that is bad - nothing is happen.

You'll need at least one function call inside, like:

```
function fn($){
  return function(){
    var innerFn = function(){
      setTimeout(show, 1000);
    };

    var show = function(){
      $.alert("TEST");
    }

    innerFn();
  }
}

fn(window)();
```

And that will works. However, it's definitely redundant. You can just have:

```
function fn($){
  return function(){
    function show(){
      $.alert("TEST");
    }

    setTimeout(show, 1000);
  }
}
```

To obtain the same result. However, if you're goal is just bound an argument to [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout), you can use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind). You could use the 3rd parameter of `setTimeout` as the documentation says, but it seems [not supported in IE for legacy reason](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536753%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

So, an example with `bind` will looks like:

```
function show() {
    this.alert('test');
}

setTimeout(show.bind(window), 1000);
```

Notice also that `window` is the global object by default, so usually you do not have to do that, just `alert` is enough. However, I suppose this is not your actual code, but just a mere test, as the alert's string says.

If you prefer having `window` as first parameter instead, and you're not interested in the context object `this`, you can do something like:

```
function show($) {
    $.alert('test');
}

setTimeout(show.bind(null, window), 1000);
```